# How to Implement Price Increase and Decrease Sorting in React Redux Application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Friends, all the good time of the day, you need to implement the sorting of goods by increasing and decreasing prices. How to write such an action.? I tried in action to write a sorting of an array of objects using the sort method. The array itself is created in the store using the React hook UseEffect as the second parameter in UseEffect, I passed this same array, but redrawing occurs only when we go to the basket and in real time we do not see redrawing . Tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is the component itself that loads products into the store and renders them:

```
function Home() {
    const books = useSelector(state=>state.books.books);
    const isFetched = useSelector(state=>state.books.isFetched);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(()=>{
      if(!books.length ){
        dispatch(setBooks())
      } 
    },[books]
);
    

    return (
       
      <Card.Group itemsPerRow={5}>
                {!isFetched ?  <Loader/> : books.map(i=>(<Books title = {i.title}
                 key={i.id}
                 author={i.author} 
                 image={i.image} 
                 price={i.price}
                 rating={i.rating}
                 />))}
        </Card.Group>
    );
}
```

And here is the reducer in which the sorting and the link for loading goods into the store are written:

```
const initialState = {
    books: [],
    isFetched: false,
}

export const SET_BOOKS = 'SET_BOOKS';


export const setBooks = (books) =>{
    return async dispatch => {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/books');
        const json = await response.json();
        dispatch({
            type: SET_BOOKS,
            payload: json
        });
    }
 }
  
 const SET_FILTER_LOWER = 'SET_FILTER_LOWER';

 export const setFilter = filter => ({
   type: SET_FILTER_LOWER,
   payload: filter,
 });

 export const setBooksReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
     switch(action.type){
        case SET_BOOKS:
            return {...state, 
                books: state.books.concat(action.payload),
                isFetched: true
            }
        case SET_FILTER_LOWER:
        return {
          ...state,
          books: action.payload.sort((a,b)=>a.price-b.price)
        //   books: action.payload.filter((el)=>el.price<=300)
        };
        default: 
        return state

     }
      
}
```

Filtering component:

```
const MenuFilter = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const books = useSelector(state=>state.books.books);
    return (
        <div className="menu_filter">
        <Menu pointing>
          <Menu.Item
            name='Дороже'
          />
          <Menu.Item
            name='Дешевле'
            onClick={()=>dispatch(setFilter(books))}
            
          />
        </Menu>

      </div>
    );
}

export default MenuFilter;
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you really need to do the sorting in a reducer?  Why not keep that behavior as a part of the display code?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your selector of books gives you an unsorted array of prices, right?

```
[
 {price: 0.99},
 {price: 1.22},
 {price: 0.49},
 {price: 0.22}
]
```

Now, instead of using books directly you could create a const that has a sorted version of that.

```
const newBooks = [...books];
```

And then sort it there.

```
newBooks.sort((book1, book2) => book1.price - book2.price))
```

And now you can map newBooks.

```
newBooks.map(i=>(<Books title = {i.title}
                 key={i.id}
                 author={i.author} 
                 image={i.image} 
                 price={i.price}
                 rating={i.rating}
                 />))
```

I do not recommend sorting it directly from books, as that would give you some unexpected behavior or updates.